# Display different messages to returning visitors and new visitors

Tags: php, mysql

I have already managed to store the visitors IP address and assign them an ID (1, 2, 3, etc.) and I want to display different messages to them. The code I have so far is this:

```
function DisplayWelcomeMessage() {
    $checkUserIDExists = mysql_query("SELECT * from Information where id = '$myid'");
    if(mysql_num_rows($checkUserIDExists) < 0) {
        return '<div class="Message">New visitor message</div>';
        } else {
        return '<div class="Message">Returning visitor message</div>';
        }
}
```

When I use this code, it always displays the returning visitor message.

Comment: ip != user, never has, never will. 1 IP can many people, one person can be many IP addresses

Comment: An alternate approach to this is to set a cookie.  It simplifies things because no database is required.  A user may clear cookies, but then again, they may not have the same IP address every time either.

Comment: @Dagon I know, but this website is simple and I really don't want to setup registrations for it.

Comment: @SurrealDreams I have no idea how to use cookies

Comment: then don't bother doing this, its meaningless if your not going to do it properly

Comment: Check out [setcookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).  If you can do database queries, you can set and check a cookie.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to set a cookie t track if they have visited the site before.

```
setcookie("FirstVisit", '1');
```

Then your welcome method would then become something like this:

```
function DisplayWelcomeMessage()
{
    if (isset($_COOKIE['FirstVisit']) && $_COOKIE['FirstVisit'] == 1)
    {
         // Display a welcome message

         // Update the cookie so that they don't get this message again
         setCookie("FirstVisit", "0");
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something different for people who have visited before
    }
}
```

You can lookup the documentation for setCookie [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Comment: Thanks, I'd use this but I need to give them an ID due to another part of my website, and I thought I would just use the same database to know if they visited before or not.

Comment: Will dropping another cookie called __id__ with the value from your database solve that problem?